# How to update values and selected index in Alert Dialog builder setSingleChoiceItems

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

This is the adapter that i am using and you can see my view inflating from custom layout and the problem here is that after clicking/pressing an item, it wont process to my Item_Selected method thats why I added a custom onClick but the problem is that I wont close the spinner after click. Badly needs help

```
{
    public class CustomSpinnerAdapter : ArrayAdapter<String> {

        String type = String.Empty;
        List<string> orderList = new List<string>();
        Context context;
        PageTaskSearchView pageTaskSearchView = new PageTaskSearchView();
        String WCName = String.Empty;
        Bundle utilBundle;
        View viewPageTask;


        /// <summary>
        /// CUstom Spinner Array Adapter constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects, String type, Bundle utilBundle, View view)
                : base(context, textViewResourceId, objects) {
            this.type = type;
            this.orderList = objects;
            this.context = context;
            this.utilBundle = utilBundle;
            this.viewPageTask = view;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// returns the total array count minus one
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>int</returns>
        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Count;
            }
        }

        public override View GetDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            var view = convertView;



            if (position == 0)
            {
                if(Constants.ORDER_LIST == type) {

                    view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomSpinnerView, null, true);
                    Switch filterOrder = (Switch) view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.switch_filterOrder);

                    int isFiltered = utilBundle.GetInt(Constants.ORDER_SWITCH_TRIGGER, 0);
                    filterOrder.Checked = Constants.ORDER_SWITCH_CLOSED == isFiltered;

                    filterOrder.CheckedChange += delegate (object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
                    {
                        int filterStatus = e.IsChecked ? Constants.ORDER_SWITCH_CLOSED : 0;
                        utilBundle.PutInt(Constants.ORDER_SWITCH_TRIGGER, filterStatus);
                        String workCenter = utilBundle.GetString(Constants.WCName, Constants.EMPTY_STRING);
                        orderList = pageTaskSearchView.retrieveOrderlist(workCenter);

                        base.Clear();
                        base.AddAll(orderList);
                        base.NotifyDataSetChanged();

                    };

                }

                else
                {
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0);
                        view = base.GetDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                        TextView tv = (TextView)view;
                        tv.SetHeight(0);
                        tv.LayoutParameters = layoutparams;
                        tv.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                        view = tv;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Constants.ORDER_LIST == type)
                {
                    view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListItemWithCheckbox, parent, false);
                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.orderLayout);
                    TextView orderId = (TextView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.listItem);

                    RadioButton selected = view.FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.checkedRadio);
                    selected.Checked = utilBundle.GetString(Constants.SELECTED_ORDER_ID, Constants.EMPTY_STRING).Equals(orderList[position]);
                    orderId.Text = orderList[position];

                    return view;

                    //view.Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
                    //{
                    //    PageTaskSearchViewModel pageTaskSearchViewModel = new PageTaskSearchViewModel(this.Context, this.viewPageTask, null, utilBundle);
                    //    pageTaskSearchViewModel.setOrderText(orderList[position]);
                    //};


                }
                else
                {
                    view = base.GetDropDownView(position, null, parent);

                }
            }

            parent.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
            return view;

        }
    }
}
```

This is my item selected method, but after pressing an item, it wont proceed to this method.

```
    spinnerSelected = (TextView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.inp_workOrder);
                    String selected = (String)spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);
                    spinnerSelected.Text = selected;
```

Comment: Hi Vince, welcome to SO. This is pure Xamarin.Android right? If it is please remove the Xamarin.Forms tag. Can be misleading.

Comment: Oh sure thing man

Comment: Hi, after updating model data , need to  `NotifyDataSetChanged()` to make view updates .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CustomSpinnerAdapter` can contain a `Update` method to reload data for adapter as follow :

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter : BaseAdapter 
{
    Context context;
    List<string> list;

    public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<string> list)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = new List<string>();
        this.list.AddRange(list) ;
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return list[position];
    }

    public void Update(List<string> newList)
    {
        list.Clear();
        list.AddRange(newList);
        NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        //return base.GetDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        var view = convertView;
        CustomSpinnerAdapterViewHolder holder = null;

        if (view != null)
            holder = view.Tag as CustomSpinnerAdapterViewHolder;

        if (holder == null)
        {
            holder = new CustomSpinnerAdapterViewHolder();
            var inflater = context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService).JavaCast<LayoutInflater>();
            //replace with your item and your holder items
            //comment back in
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Itemlayout, parent, false);
            holder.Title = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            view.Tag = holder;
            holder.Title.Text = GetItem(position).ToString();
        }
        //fill in your items


        return view;
    }

    public override View GetDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        //return base.GetDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        var view = convertView;
        CustomSpinnerAdapterViewHolder holder = null;

        if (view != null)
            holder = view.Tag as CustomSpinnerAdapterViewHolder;

        if (holder == null)
        {
            holder = new CustomSpinnerAdapterViewHolder();
            var inflater = context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService).JavaCast<LayoutInflater>();
            //replace with your item and your holder items
            //comment back in
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layoutDrop, parent, false);
            holder.Title = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            view.Tag = holder;
            holder.Title.Text = list[position];
        }
        //fill in your items


        return view;
    }

    //Fill in cound here, currently 0
    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return list.Count;
        }
    }

}

class CustomSpinnerAdapterViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
    //Your adapter views to re-use
    public TextView Title { get; set; }
}
```

In **Activity** , init `CustomSpinnerAdapter` for Spinner :

```
customAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, planetNames);
spinner.Adapter = customAdapter;
spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(spinner_ItemSelected);
```

Then in `ItemSelected` method , when modifying data , you can invoke `Update` Method :

```
private void spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
    string toast = string.Format("The planet is {0}", spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position));
    Toast.MakeText(this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show();

    if (isFirstShow)
    {
        isFirstShow = false;
        return;
    }

    Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    Android.App.AlertDialog alert = dialog.Create();
    alert.SetTitle("Title");
    alert.SetMessage("Change data for spinner !");
    alert.SetButton("OK", (c, ev) =>
    {
        // Ok button click task  
        planetNames[e.Position] = "new data";
        customAdapter.Update(planetNames);
        Console.WriteLine("Modified!");
    });
    alert.Show();
}
```

The effect as follow :

[image]

================================Update==================================

**Itemlayout.xml** : Spinner undropdown view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="getView()"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**layoutDrop.xml** : Spinner Dropdown view

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="getDropDownView()"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />

</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: Hi sir. I am using SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);. My problem is that after  this line 
 list.Clear();
 list.AddRange(newList);
NotifyDataSetChanged();

the checked radio is still checked

Comment: @VinceGeralddelaCerna You can share more explains about the problem . You mean want to the selected option unselected ?

Comment: OrderIdAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem); 
try adding this to your code sir to see difference, it has a radio-check display

Comment: @VinceGeralddelaCerna You can have a look at my `CustomSpinnerAdapter` , there is a  `GetDropDownView` method , that custom the dropdown view .So my method not need to use `SetDropDownViewResource` and can not invoke that .

Comment: @VinceGeralddelaCerna You can share a gif screenshot here and `CustomSpinnerAdapter` code . My `CustomSpinnerAdapter` inherit from `BaseAdapter` , I want to have a look at yours .

Comment: Ahh I see, let me try that sir.

Comment: @VinceGeralddelaCerna I have updated answer, if works let me know that :-)

Comment: I got it already dude. Thanks. But i have a problem, after clicking an item, the spinner wont close.

Comment: @VinceGeralddelaCerna Okey , if answer be helpful can mark it .And you can see my shared gif , the spinner closed by shared code . I think you will find the where reason is .

Comment: I used inflater sir, but somehow if I click on the item, it wont be proceed to my spinner_ItemSelected method. Any reasons as to why?

Comment: @VinceGeralddelaCerna You can share your full code in question , I will check that .

Comment: Mine inherits from ArrayAdapter

Comment: @VinceGeralddelaCerna Okey , why not using `BaseAdapter` . `ArrayAdapter` has some limition when customing adapter for spinner. You can modoify my code to fit your needs , the dropdown view can be customed . I have updated the layout code of dropdown view and content view of spinner .

Comment: My only issue is if i press/click on an item in my spinner, it wont proceed on my on item selected.

Comment: @VinceGeralddelaCerna Okey  , my local site can not reproduce it . From shared code  , can not know where problem is .You can share full code of your adapter in question .

Comment: @VinceGeralddelaCerna Okey , I think the reason is about the follow logic `if (position == 0){if(Constants.ORDER_LIST == type) {` in your project .You can have a check at this . Cancel judgment to check if it can be displayed normally .

Comment: I ll remove it?

Comment: The reason for that is at position 0, I have this custom layout for my switch filter that will filter the list if it is closed or not

Comment: @VinceGeralddelaCerna Hi , have you found where the reason is ?

Comment: Jiang. Yes sir, the only reason that my custom adapter didnt proceed to the item selected method because child layout(the textview and the radio button) was clicked not the parent. I just added android:focusable="false" to child layout and after that, it proceeded to my item selected method. THanks a lot sir

Comment: @VinceGeralddelaCerna Great ! Glad you find the reason wherer is :-)